# Upload a folder to server wtih laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I am trying to write a script which allows user to upload folder. Basically the user will specify a folder, and all files contained should be uploaded, with relative path or folder structure reconstructed on the server.

The html part uses `webkitdirectory`,

```
<form action="cmd/test" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input id="upload" name="content[]" type="file" value="Input" directory webkitdirectory>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

And the server is written in Laravel. I was hoping to use the `Request` in Laravel, like

```
Route::any('cmd/test', function(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    echo $request;
    $files = $request->file('content');
    echo json_encode($files);
    //Store the files here...
});
```

I tried to upload a test folder, with the following content:

```
dir /s test

 Directory of C:\Users\███████\Desktop\test

18-Nov-18  05:19 PM    <DIR>          .
18-Nov-18  05:19 PM    <DIR>          ..
18-Nov-18  05:19 PM                 1 note1.txt
18-Nov-18  05:19 PM                 1 note2.txt
18-Nov-18  05:20 PM    <DIR>          test1
               2 File(s)              2 bytes

 Directory of C:\Users\███████\Desktop\test\test1

18-Nov-18  05:20 PM    <DIR>          .
18-Nov-18  05:20 PM    <DIR>          ..
18-Nov-18  05:20 PM                 1 note3.txt
               1 File(s)              1 bytes

     Total Files Listed:
               3 File(s)              3 bytes
```

---

<del>To my surprise, the output of the test script is</del>

```
[{},{},{}]
```

<del>No information on the file name or content is retrieved with `Request::file()`. Same result with either Edge or Firefox. Any suggestions?</del>

---

EDIT: That's basically my bad to not realize the type of return value is `UploadedFile`. The problem on getting the relative path of the files to reconstruct folder structure remains tho.

Comment: May be relevant: `$_FILES['content']['name']` does return `["note1.txt", "note2.txt", "note3.txt"]`, so the server does receive something about the files.

Comment: Just a note as of 2018, **do not use webkitdirectory for production** (source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/webkitdirectory)).

Comment: Tryied it in plain PHP on Chrome 70.0.3538.102 @ Windows 8, I get my files correctly. What does `$files` contains when you try it on your side?

Comment: Tryied on a hole new laravel 5.7 project, still trying on my Chrome, works ok I got this: https://ibb.co/jjTmS0

Comment: try to edit  name="content[]"   to name="content"

Comment: @Anwar Tried again it actually worked but I was dumb enough to not realize that 1. phpstorm does not realize `$files` was an array of `UploadedFile`; 2. `json_encode` tells nothing about the content of `UploadedFile`. Thanks