# Folder upload Laravel

Tags: laravel, file-upload

I am trying to upload a directory in laravel, here is my front end code

```
<form action="{{route('documents.upload.folder')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <input type="file" name="file[]" directory webkitdirectory  >
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>

<script>
    // JavaScript
    const form = document.querySelector('form');
    form.addEventListener('submit', async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData(form);
        console.log('form data',formData)
        const response = await fetch('{{route('documents.upload.folder')}}', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData,
        });
        console.log(await response);
    });
</script>
```

in the backend when I die dump, it shows only files not folders inside
here is the screenshot:
[image]

I am wondering if any body knows how to upload folder with contents  in laravel thanks in advance!

I am trying to upload folders with its content, but folders are not uploading in the server

Comment: some [tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53359474/upload-a-folder-to-server-wtih-laravel) of webkitdirectory  and how to do it.

Comment: my question is does http request allows web browser to upload folders ?

Comment: I am not sure, but in google drive and drop box you can upload folders